# There are two ways for calculating loop gain. Which one is the correct loop gain?

Tags: loop-gain

The following is a question from 8.18 in  *[Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf)*, page 342.

Consider the circuit in this following figure. \$(\frac{W} {L})_{1-4} =\frac{50} {0.5} \$, \$|{I_D}_{1-4}| = 0.5\ \mathrm{mA}\$, \$R_2 = 3\ \mathrm{k\Omega}\$.

[image]

Calculate the closed-loop gain and output impedance.

The answer I found from internet ([solution link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5l5JHTunnJiZWM1YWRjMTctMDYxNi00ZDZkLTk2OTAtZTE1MzJiZTU2Nzlm/view?resourcekey=0-OQwkkoFwDWJhUndfr72e8A)).

[image]

$$A \beta = \frac{V_F} {V_t}$$

Some book said

[image]

$$A \beta = \frac{V_{out}} {V_{test}}$$

My question is, which is the  loop gain?

Comment: @ kile - as we have already discussed in another thread from you: If the opening of the loop significantly changes the load at this node, this load must be restored using additional elements. Now you can check your circuits if this requirement (at the node named Vout) is fulfilled or not.

Comment: @Lvw What you said was very abstract. do you have any concrete examples?

Comment: Are you using those schematics in ltspice to simulate loop gain? Or just for illustration purposes? If it's the first, then you'll never be able to simulate loop gain in this way.

Comment: @kile - your circuit is the best example: By simple visual inspection you can identify the circuitry  wich forms the load that was connected to the respective node before opening. In some corresponding papers it is recommended to mirror the complete circuit which was connected to this node. However, in your case, I think it will be sufficient to consider  R1, R2 and M1 only (as given in the first circuit).

Comment: @Designalog I am just using it illustration. Which one is the correct to calculate loop gain \$A \beta\$ in your opinion?

Comment: @LvW Do you mean both of them are correct?

Comment: @kile - please be exact and detailed in your questions. What do you mean with "them"? Circuits, equations or results?

Comment: @LvW I have proposed two ways of finding loop gain \$A \beta\$. one is from the Google drive solution,  the other is from some books. Which one is the correct one?

Comment: @kile The two circuits do not seem to be the same. What is the second circuit before breaking the loop?

Comment: @kile - don`t you remember ? This question was discussed in detail in another (former) thread from you. Nevertheless - my answer is: Both are wrong!  Please remember the missing influence of the input impedance (1/gm) at the source of M1. And the second circuit has no load at all at the node Vout.

Comment: @internet This is the circuit before breaking the loop. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPbXx.png

Comment: The circuit that includes the loading effect is "more" correct way of finding the loop gain.  This one https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Jbex.png