# What voltage should I choose in in order to make sure all transistor are in saturation in LTspice?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

This is my circuit schematic

[image]

I have tried to use `.dc` for Vicm, VDD and VB. But all I have tried seemed to be in vain.
I can't make all of them work in saturation mode.

Here is asc file.

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1048 680
WIRE 80 32 -160 32
WIRE 160 32 80 32
WIRE 208 32 160 32
WIRE 288 32 208 32
WIRE 32 48 0 48
WIRE 400 48 336 48
WIRE -160 64 -160 32
WIRE 160 80 160 32
WIRE 160 80 80 80
WIRE 208 80 208 32
WIRE 288 80 208 80
WIRE 288 144 288 128
WIRE 416 144 288 144
WIRE 464 144 416 144
WIRE -160 160 -160 144
WIRE 80 160 80 128
WIRE 96 160 80 160
WIRE 592 160 592 112
WIRE 752 160 752 112
WIRE 80 192 80 160
WIRE 192 192 80 192
WIRE 896 192 896 112
WIRE 80 208 80 192
WIRE 288 208 288 144
WIRE 128 256 80 256
WIRE 368 256 288 256
WIRE -16 288 -16 240
WIRE -16 288 -96 288
WIRE 32 288 -16 288
WIRE 192 288 192 192
WIRE 240 288 192 288
WIRE 80 320 80 304
WIRE 96 320 80 320
WIRE 288 320 288 304
WIRE 80 352 80 320
WIRE 160 352 80 352
WIRE 416 352 416 224
WIRE 448 352 416 352
WIRE 416 384 416 352
WIRE -96 400 -96 368
WIRE 160 432 80 432
WIRE 80 464 80 432
WIRE 592 464 592 240
WIRE 592 464 416 464
WIRE 752 464 752 240
WIRE 752 464 592 464
WIRE 896 464 896 272
WIRE 896 464 752 464
WIRE 416 480 416 464
FLAG -160 160 0
FLAG 464 144 Vout
IOPIN 464 144 Out
FLAG 416 480 0
FLAG -96 400 0
FLAG 592 112 Vicm
FLAG 752 112 Vid
FLAG 896 112 VB
FLAG 400 48 VB
FLAG 0 48 VB
FLAG 96 160 Vx
IOPIN 96 160 Out
FLAG 288 320 0
FLAG 448 352 VF
IOPIN 448 352 Out
FLAG 128 256 0
FLAG 368 256 0
FLAG -160 32 VDD
FLAG 80 464 0
FLAG 96 320 VS
IOPIN 96 320 Out
FLAG -16 240 Vin
IOPIN -16 240 In
SYMBOL nmos4 32 208 R0
SYMATTR InstName M1
SYMATTR Value NMOS-SH
SYMATTR Value2 l=0.5u w=50u
SYMBOL nmos4 240 208 R0
SYMATTR InstName M2
SYMATTR Value NMOS-SH
SYMATTR Value2 l=0.5u w=50u
SYMBOL pmos4 32 128 M180
SYMATTR InstName M3
SYMATTR Value PMOS-SH
SYMATTR Value2 l=0.5u w=50u
SYMBOL pmos4 336 128 R180
WINDOW 3 -109 47 Left 2
SYMATTR Value PMOS-SH
SYMATTR InstName M4
SYMATTR Value2 l=0.5u w=50u
SYMBOL res 400 368 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL res 400 128 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL voltage -160 48 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName VDD
SYMATTR Value 3
SYMBOL bv -96 272 R0
WINDOW 3 -107 102 Left 2
SYMATTR Value V=V(Vicm)+V(Vid)
SYMATTR InstName Vin
SYMBOL voltage 592 144 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName Vicm
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL voltage 752 144 R0
WINDOW 3 24 152 Left 2
WINDOW 123 24 124 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value 0
SYMATTR Value2 AC 1
SYMATTR InstName Vid
SYMBOL voltage 896 176 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName VB
SYMATTR Value 2
SYMBOL res 64 336 R0
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL res 144 336 R0
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 1k
TEXT -72 -72 Left 2 !;tf V(Vout) Vid
TEXT -96 -120 Left 2 !.MODEL PMOS-SH pmos(kp=45u,vto=-0.42, lambda = {0.14/1})
TEXT -96 -144 Left 2 !.MODEL NMOS-SH nmos(kp=180u,vto=0.4, lambda = {0.1/1})
TEXT -72 -40 Left 2 !;dc Vicm 0 5 0.01
TEXT 176 -72 Left 2 !;ac oct 10 100MEG 100G\n.op
TEXT -72 -16 Left 2 !;dc VDD 0 5 0.01
TEXT -72 8 Left 2 !;dc VB 0 5 0.01
```

Comment: Did you make any calculations? Or did you just pick ‘random’ MOS transistors without any calculations?

Comment: I make simple hand calculations. For NMOS in saturation, 
$$V_{GT} = |V_{GS} - V_{T_n}| < V_{DS}$$

For PMOS
$$ V_{SG} - |V_{T_p}| < V_{DS}$$

Besides that, I use `.dc` scan for this. But It seemed impossible to achieve all demands

Comment: @kile You just randomly pick W/L, which is why it doesn't work.

Comment: @internet W = 50u , L= 0.5u. It is not displayed on LTspice.

Comment: @kile I knew that, but that is kind of randomly picked for all transistors.

Comment: @internet Do you mean W = 50u , L= 0.5u is a randomly picked value?

Comment: @kile You just picked the same size for all transistors.

Comment: @internet The question from the book did that. I am just following what the book said

Comment: @kile can you post the question from the book as well?

Comment: @internet https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/706155/there-are-two-ways-for-calculating-loop-gain-which-one-is-the-correct-loop-gain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few small changes
[image]

[image]

It seems like you still don't really understand how the amplifier should work.

Here is asc file.

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1128 680
WIRE 80 32 -160 32
WIRE 160 32 80 32
WIRE 208 32 160 32
WIRE 288 32 208 32
WIRE 32 48 0 48
WIRE 400 48 336 48
WIRE -160 64 -160 32
WIRE 160 80 160 32
WIRE 160 80 80 80
WIRE 208 80 208 32
WIRE 288 80 208 80
WIRE 288 144 288 128
WIRE 416 144 288 144
WIRE 464 144 416 144
WIRE -160 160 -160 144
WIRE 80 160 80 128
WIRE 96 160 80 160
WIRE 592 160 592 112
WIRE 752 160 752 112
WIRE 80 192 80 160
WIRE 192 192 80 192
WIRE 896 192 896 112
WIRE 80 208 80 192
WIRE 288 208 288 144
WIRE 1056 208 1056 128
WIRE 128 256 80 256
WIRE 336 256 288 256
WIRE -16 288 -16 240
WIRE -16 288 -96 288
WIRE 32 288 -16 288
WIRE 192 288 192 192
WIRE 240 288 192 288
WIRE 80 320 80 304
WIRE 96 320 80 320
WIRE 80 352 80 320
WIRE 160 352 80 352
WIRE 416 352 416 224
WIRE 448 352 416 352
WIRE 416 384 416 352
WIRE -96 400 -96 368
WIRE 160 432 80 432
WIRE 288 432 288 304
WIRE 80 464 80 432
WIRE 592 464 592 240
WIRE 592 464 416 464
WIRE 752 464 752 240
WIRE 752 464 592 464
WIRE 896 464 896 272
WIRE 896 464 752 464
WIRE 1056 464 1056 288
WIRE 1056 464 896 464
WIRE 416 480 416 464
FLAG -160 160 0
FLAG 464 144 Vout
IOPIN 464 144 Out
FLAG 416 480 0
FLAG -96 400 0
FLAG 592 112 Vicm
FLAG 752 112 Vid
FLAG 896 112 VB
FLAG 400 48 VB2
FLAG 0 48 VB
FLAG 96 160 Vx
IOPIN 96 160 Out
FLAG 288 432 0
FLAG 448 352 VF
IOPIN 448 352 Out
FLAG 128 256 0
FLAG 336 256 0
FLAG -160 32 VDD
FLAG 80 464 0
FLAG 96 320 VS
IOPIN 96 320 Out
FLAG -16 240 Vin
IOPIN -16 240 In
FLAG 1056 128 VB2
SYMBOL nmos4 32 208 R0
SYMATTR InstName M1
SYMATTR Value NMOS-SH
SYMATTR Value2 l=0.5u w=50u
SYMBOL nmos4 240 208 R0
SYMATTR InstName M2
SYMATTR Value NMOS-SH2
SYMATTR Value2 l=0.5u w=50u
SYMBOL pmos4 32 128 M180
SYMATTR InstName M3
SYMATTR Value PMOS-SH
SYMATTR Value2 l=0.5u w=50u
SYMBOL pmos4 336 128 R180
WINDOW 3 -109 47 Left 2
SYMATTR Value PMOS-SH
SYMATTR InstName M4
SYMATTR Value2 l=0.5u w=50u
SYMBOL res 400 368 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL res 400 128 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL voltage -160 48 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName VDD
SYMATTR Value 3
SYMBOL voltage 592 144 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName Vicm
SYMATTR Value 952mV
SYMBOL voltage 752 144 R0
WINDOW 3 -43 343 Left 2
WINDOW 123 24 124 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value SINE(0 1m 1k)
SYMATTR Value2 AC 1
SYMATTR InstName Vid
SYMBOL voltage 896 176 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName VB
SYMATTR Value 2.4
SYMBOL res 64 336 R0
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL res 144 336 R0
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL voltage 1056 192 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName VB2
SYMATTR Value 2
SYMBOL bv -96 272 R0
WINDOW 3 -85 180 Left 2
WINDOW 0 -27 -3 Left 2
SYMATTR Value V=V(Vicm)+V(Vid)
SYMATTR InstName Vin1
TEXT -96 -120 Left 2 !.MODEL PMOS-SH pmos(kp=45u,vto=-0.42, lambda = {0.14/1})
TEXT -96 -144 Left 2 !.MODEL NMOS-SH nmos(kp=180u,vto=0.4, lambda = {0.1/1})
TEXT 176 -72 Left 2 !;ac oct 110 10 1Meg\n;op
TEXT -96 -168 Left 2 !.MODEL NMOS-SH2 nmos(kp=450u,vto=1.05 lambda = {0.14/1})
TEXT 176 -16 Left 2 !.tran 0 5m 0 1u
```

Comment: The DC biased voltage should be the same according to the original question (the biased M1 and M4 is connected together).
I don't know why you choose different voltage. Could you explain the reason?

Comment: I did it out of sheer laziness. I simply didn’t want to do detailed calculations.

Comment: Why did you create `.MODEL NMOS-SH2 nmos(kp=450u,vto=1.05 lambda = {0.14/1})`? The original  question requires  all nmos to be the same.

Comment: @kile Because Vx is quite large (compared to the threshold voltage), so if you use a normal MOSFET, the output swing has to be reduced to keep these transistors in saturation.